# How can I check if Bundle.module is defined?

Tags: ios, cocoapods, swift5, nsbundle, swift-package-manager

In my iOS app I am using SPM to manage dependencies. One of them is a library that loads resources with `Bundle.module` (a new feature available in Swift 5.3). But now I need to use CocoaPods for my app. Hence, I should add CocoaPods support for this dependency. I know that I can copy `Bundle.module`'s declaration from **resource_bundle_accessor.swift** to the library. But it should also support SPM. I want to know how can I check if I should use `Bundle.module` defined in **resource_bundle_accessor.swift** or my function that does the same thing if **resource_bundle_accessor.swift** was not generated.

Comment: Why would the pod need to know anything about the internal code of the package? If the package has resources, `Bundle.module` will be defined internally as far as the package's code is concerned; what else is there to know?

Comment: @matt I need to fix this line `let someResourceURL = Bundle.module.url(forResource: "resource", withExtension: "txt")` when the library is installed through CocoaPods.

Comment: I see! So it sounds like being a Swift Package and being a CocoaPod are incompatible goals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option it to use `#if SWIFT_PACKAGE` to distinguish between SPM and CocoaPods specific code.  Here's an example of how we set up a test to run with both package managers: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/FirebaseRemoteConfig/Tests/Unit/RCNRemoteConfigTest.m#L1144